# Changing State for an object in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

firstly i would like to apologise for being a complete novice but I have researched the web and can not find a solution to my current problem.
I have 3 objects (sprites) that i have set up individually with switch statements and want to use my main gameplay layer to change their states randomly to an animation that i have already defined in the objects individual header and implementation files.
I have set up a self schedule updater and arc4random method that works but it will not change the state of the object, as it only calls the CCLOG that I have also included in the statement.

I have listed to code below and i know it is a bit of a mess but still very much in my first steps of being a beginner, if anyone can point me in the right direction (that's if i have explained this in a way you can understand!) I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for even looking at this question.

```
    //-------------------below is my gameplaylayer header file---------//

//  GamePlayLayer.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCLayer.h"
#import "SneakyJoystick.h"
#import "SneakyButton.h"
#import "SneakyButtonSkinnedBase.h"
#import "SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "CommonProtocols.h"
#import "TBT.h"
#import "MBT.h"
#import "BBT.h"
#import "BC.h"
#import "GameCharacter.h"
#import <stdlib.h>

@interface GamePlayLayer : CCLayer <GamePlayLayerDelegate> {
    CCSprite *vikingSprite;

    SneakyJoystick *leftJoystick;
    SneakyButton *jumpButton;
    SneakyButton *attackButton;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *sceneSpriteBatchNode;

}
@property (readwrite) CharacterStates characterState;


-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState;
-(void)addEnemy;
@end

//---------------------Below is my gameplaylayer implementation file-------------//

//  GamePlayLayer.m

#import "GamePlayLayer.h"

@implementation GamePlayLayer
@synthesize characterState;


-(void) dealloc {
    [leftJoystick release];
    [jumpButton release];
    [attackButton release];
    [super dealloc];
    }

-(void)initJoystickAndButtons {
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

//---DELETED MOST OF THE ABOVE METHOD AS NOT NEEDED FOR THIS QUESTION----//

-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects =
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode children];                     
    for (GameCharacter *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) {         
        [tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];                         
    }
}
-(void) createObjectOfType: (GameObjectType)objectType
                withHealth:(int)initialHealth atLocation:(CGPoint)spawnLocation withZValue:(int)ZValue {
    if (objectType == kEnemyType1BT) {
        CCLOG(@"creating the 1BT");
        TBT *tBT = [[TBT alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"BT_anim_1.png"];
        [tBT setCharacterHealth:initialHealth];
        [tBT setPosition:spawnLocation];
        [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:tBT
                                     z:ZValue
                                   tag:k1BTtagValue];
        [tBT release];} 

    if (objectType == kEnemyType3BT){
        CCLOG(@"creating the radar enemy");
        BBT *bBT = [[BBT alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"BT_anim_1.png"];
        [bBT setCharacterHealth:initialHealth];
        [bBT setPosition:spawnLocation];
        [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:bBT
                                     z:ZValue
                                   tag:k3BTtagValue];
        [bBT release];
    }

    if (objectType == kEnemyType2BT){
        CCLOG(@"creating the radar enemy");
        MBT *mBT = [[MBT alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"BT_anim_1.png"];
        [mBT setCharacterHealth:initialHealth];
        [mBT setPosition:spawnLocation];
        [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:mBT
                                     z:ZValue
                                   tag:k2BTtagValue];
        [mBT release];
    }
}

//--PROBLEM I HAVE IS BELOW--//

-(void)addEnemy {
    int x =  (arc4random() % 3);
    TBT *tBT = (TBT*)
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode getChildByTag:kEnemyType1BT];

    //--Just using one object(sprite) to begin with--//

    if (x>0) {
        CCLOG(@"RANDOM KSTATETEST!!!!!!");
        [tBT changeState:kStatetest];  <---it is not changing state to kStatetest
      }

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self !=nil) {

        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector]. winSize;
self.TouchEnabled = YES;

        srandom(time(NULL));

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
             addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlas.plist"];          // 1
            sceneSpriteBatchNode =
            [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlas.png"]; // 2
        } else {
            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
             addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlasiPhone.plist"];          // 1
            sceneSpriteBatchNode =
            [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlasiPhone.png"];// 2
        }


        [self addChild:sceneSpriteBatchNode z:0];                // 3
        [self initJoystickAndButtons];                           // 4
        BC *viking = [[BC alloc]
                          initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache
                                                sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                                               spriteFrameByName:@"BCmoving_anim_1.png"]];            
        //[viking setJoystick:leftJoystick];
        [viking setJumpButton:jumpButton];
        [viking setAttackButton:attackButton];
        [viking setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.19f,
                                screenSize.height * 0.19f)];
        [viking setCharacterHealth:3];

        [sceneSpriteBatchNode
         addChild:viking
         z:kVikingSpriteZValue
         tag:kVikingSpriteTagValue];           heatlh is set to 100

     [self schedule:@selector(addEnemy) interval:1.0f];


        [self createObjectOfType:kEnemyType1BT withHealth:3 atLocation:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.0439f, screenSize.height * 0.822f) withZValue:10];


        [self createObjectOfType:kEnemyType3BT withHealth:3 atLocation:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.0439f, screenSize.height * 0.45f) withZValue:10];

        [self createObjectOfType:kEnemyType2BT withHealth:3 atLocation:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.0439f, screenSize.height * 0.638f) withZValue:10];
               //Sets up the schedular call that will fire the update method in GamePlayLayer.m every frame.
        [self scheduleUpdate];


    }

    return self;

}

@end
```

//----------------- below is one of my objects header files--------------//

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GameCharacter.h"


@interface TBT : GameCharacter{

    CCAnimation *tiltingAnim;
    CCAnimation *transmittingAnim;
    CCAnimation *loseLifeAnim;
    CCAnimation *throwingAnim;
    CCAnimation *afterThrowingAnim;    
    CCAnimation *shootPhaserAnim;    

    GameCharacter *vikingCharacter;
    id <GamePlayLayerDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <GamePlayLayerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *tiltingAnim;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *transmittingAnim;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *takingAHitAnim;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *loseLifeAnim;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *throwingAnim;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCAnimation *afterThrowingAnim;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCAnimation *shootPhaserAnim;

-(void)initAnimations;


@end


//-----------------below is the .m file for one of my objects--------------//

#import "TBT.h"

@implementation TBT

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize tiltingAnim;
@synthesize transmittingAnim;
@synthesize loseLifeAnim;
@synthesize throwingAnim;
@synthesize afterThrowingAnim;
@synthesize shootPhaserAnim;



-(void) dealloc {
    delegate = nil;

    [tiltingAnim release];
    [transmittingAnim release];
    [loseLifeAnim release];
    [throwingAnim release];
    [afterThrowingAnim release];
    [shootPhaserAnim release];

    [super dealloc];
}


-(void)shootPhaser {
    CGPoint phaserFiringPosition;
    PhaserDirection phaserDir;
    CGRect boundingBox = [self boundingBox];
    CGPoint position = [self position];

    float xPosition = position.x + boundingBox.size.width * 0.542f;
    float yPosition = position.y + boundingBox.size.height * 0.25f;

    if ([self flipX]) {
        CCLOG(@"TBT Facing right, Firing to the right");
        phaserDir = kDirectionRight;
    } else {
        CCLOG(@"TBT Facing left, Firing to the left");
        xPosition = xPosition * -1.0f;
        phaserDir = kDirectionLeft;
    }
    phaserFiringPosition = ccp(xPosition, yPosition);
    [delegate createPhaserWithDirection:phaserDir andPosition:phaserFiringPosition];
}

-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState {
    [self stopAllActions];
    id action = nil;
    [self setCharacterState:newState];

    switch (newState) {
        case kStatespawning:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->Changing State to Spwaning");
            [self setDisplayFrame:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
              spriteFrameByName:@"BT_anim_1.png"]];
            break;


        case kStateIdle:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->schaning state to idle");
            [self setDisplayFrame:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
              spriteFrameByName:@"BT_anim_1.png"]];

            break;

        case kStatetest:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->Changing State to test");
            action = [CCSequence actions : [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.5f],[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:transmittingAnim], nil];
            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"unhandled state %d in TBT", newState);
            break;
    }

    if (action !=nil) {
        [self runAction:action];

    }
}

-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime: (ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray*)listOfGameObjects {

    if (characterState == kStateDead)
        return;

    if ((([self numberOfRunningActions] == 0) && (characterState != kStateDead)) ) {
        CCLOG(@"TBT Going to Idle");
        [self changeState:kStateIdle];
        return;
    }

}


-(void)initAnimations {
    [self setTiltingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"tiltingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];

    [self setTransmittingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"transmittingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];

}

-(id) initWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)frameName{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:frameName])) {
            CCLOG(@"### TBT initialized");
            [self initAnimations];
            characterHealth = 3.0f;
            gameObjectType = kEnemyType1BT;
            [self changeState:kStatespawning];
        }}
    return self;

}

@end
```

Comment: is -(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState even called in your object?

Comment: you should probably move "-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState;" from your GamePlayLayer.h class to your object's header-file.

Comment: Hi Mikael, thanks for the response. The (characterState) method was called in the objects .m file and then (what i thought i was doing anyway!) importing it to the gameplaylayer.

Comment: Also i tried your suggestion and unfortunately i still have the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on -(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState? What's the status on 'newState'? What does your log say?

Comment: Hi again Mikael, thanks once again for the quick response and i do apologise for my long one but have been at work and am learning in my spare time. I have placed a breakpoint in my objects .m file at -(void)changeState as you have advised and the log says..'creating 1BT' 'gameObject init' ###TBT initialised.

Comment: If i change the objects starting state to kstateTest and run the program then it works and keeps looping the animation which leads me (with my very limited knowledge) to think that it is a problem with the gamePlayLayer.m file. Not sure if i need to make some kind of array to keep track of what state the object is currently in but was hoping it would be easier than that. Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: Just want to say i have finally found out what was wrong but just want to say thanks again Mikael

Comment: Great to hear Rob. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out that all I needed was to add the following code to my TBT gameCharacters-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime: method...

if (characterState == kStateTest) {

```
    if (characterState != kStateTest) {
        [self changeState:kStateTest];
        return;
    }
```

now it works fine.

Thanks again to Mikael for trying to help me.